# Showing the element's name or emoji on click in React, getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my component:

```
const Card = ({ _name, emoji, logger }) => {
  return (
    <div style={styles.wrapper}>
      <button onClick={logger}>-</button>
      <h4>
        {_name} {emoji}
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is my `App.js`:

```
const arr = [
  { _name: 'Apple', emoji: '', id: '01' },
  { _name: 'Banana', emoji: '', id: '02' },
  { _name: 'Peach', emoji: '', id: '03' },
  { _name: 'Pineapple', emoji: '', id: '04' },
  { _name: 'Mango', emoji: '', id: '05' },
  { _name: 'Melon', emoji: '', id: '06' },
];

const App = () => {
  const logger = (el) => {
    alert(el.target.value.emoji);
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.wrapper}>
      {arr.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Card
            _name={item._name}
            emoji={item.emoji}
            key={item.id}
            logger={logger}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm trying to show the element emoji when you click on it. When I click on each item I got `undefined`. Why is that? What is the problem?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski what do you mean by crucial part of Card component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter that gets passed to your click handler dosent't have a `target.value.emoji`, that's why you are getting `undefined`.

One way to do what you want is to change `logger` to this:

```
const logger = (emoji) => {
  alert(emoji);
};
```

And `Card` component to:

```
const Card = ({ _name, emoji, logger }) => {
  return (
    <div style={styles.wrapper}>
      <button onClick={e => logger(emoji)}>-</button>
      <h4>
        {_name} {emoji}
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```